# C# Windows Phone Mango - Invalid cross-thread access? parsing XML

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, url, error-handling

I have the following code which seems to throw a "Invalid cross-thread access." and I can't seem to figure out why. I'm loading a remote xml file from a URL, however, when parsing that XML I always receive this error. Any suggestions?

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string xml = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
            {

                    reader.ReadToFollowing("channel");
                    reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();

                    reader.ReadToFollowing("title");
                    output.AppendLine("Title: " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                    reader.ReadToFollowing("description");
                    output.AppendLine("Desc: " + reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                    textBox1.Text = output.ToString(); //Invalid cross-thread access.
            }

        }
```

The XML I'm trying to parse looks like the following, I'm just trying to parse bits and pieces as I continue to learn how to use c# to parse different types of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"xmlns:dc="http://purl.org   /dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0  /modules/slash/">
  <channel>
<title>Server &amp; Site News</title>
<description>A place for the Admin and Moderators to post the latest news on both the server and site.</description>
<pubDate>Fri, 18 May 2012 22:45:08 +0000</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Fri, 18 May 2012 22:45:08 +0000</lastBuildDate>
<generator>Forums</generator>
<link>http://removedurl.com/forums/server-site-news.23/</link>
<atom:link rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://removedurl.com/forums/server-site-news.23/index.rss"/>
<item>
  <title>Example Title</title>
  <pubDate>Mon, 14 May 2012 17:39:45 +0000</pubDate>
  <link>http://removedurl.com/threads/back-fully-working.11013/</link>
  <guid>http://removedurl.com/threadsback-fully-working.11013/</guid>
  <author>Admin</author>
  <dc:creator>Admin</dc:creator>
  <slash:comments>14</slash:comments>
</item>
</channel>
```

Comment: -1 Have you tried to google your error `Invalid cross-thread access` ?. Duplicate of billions of similar questions

Comment: I did actually see the many other errors, however, I required further clarification, which Mayank provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

textBox1.Text = output.ToString(); //Invalid cross-thread access.

you get that because you are calling UI thread while you are doing operations on IO thread. Try separating those operations or call `invoke` on the UI thread.

try changing your code to something like this.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => { //your ui update code } );
```

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit more detail from Mayank:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => {
  textBox1.Text = output.ToString()
} );
```

You have to marshal the call to UI objects back to the UI thread.  Nothing can modify UI elements on any other thread than the main one.